# Find first available data source with jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

So I was asked this at an interview, but it brought up a good use case. Assume that you have a bunch of data sources. You want to find the first available one and process it and ignore the rest.

So something like:

```
var datasources = new Array("somedatabase1/pizza","somedatabase2/beer","somedatabase3/llama");
var dfds = new Array();
$.each(datasources,function(source){
    dfds.push($.getJSON(source));
});

$.when(dfds).done(function(){alert("they are all done");});
```

Ignore that I really don't think when accepts an array (maybe it does). This of course would make it wait till they are all completed. I am looking for some code that would make it wait until one, any of them is done, and then not worry about the others.

I was informed that it would only work recursively.

Comment: Should they all start at the same time, or the second one when the first failed?

Comment: @Bergi I think either will work, I think both are optimal in various use cases.

Comment: Yes, but their concept is very different. So which one do you need?

Comment: I filed another feature request against jQuery for this and related enhancements to `$.when()`: **[OPTIONS PARAMETER FOR $.WHEN() TO PROVIDE ALTERNATIVE SEMANTICS](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12325)**. It was also closed but [jaubourg](https://github.com/jaubourg) added good analysis and suggestions that will help anyone interested in this question.

Comment: @hippietrail that is awesome! Thanks for posting the link.

Comment: @Parris: You're welcome. In fact I've now sat down and made a version of `$.when()` with inverted logic: Wait for first `resolve` or all `reject`s. I'll post it in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't use recursion but fits the requirement to fetch from multiple datasources and only care about the first that returns a successful response.

http://jsfiddle.net/mNJ6D/

```
function raceToIt(urls) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        promises;

    function anyComplete(data) {
        if (!deferred.isResolved()) {
            deferred.resolveWith(this, [data]);
            promises.forEach(function(promise) {
                promise.abort();
            });
        }
    }
    promises = urls.map(function(url) {
        return $.getJSON(url).then(anyComplete);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
raceToIt(["/echo/json/", "/echo/json/", "/echo/json/"]).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});​
```

Comment: This is actually pretty awesome, and it lets you start them all at once! Perhaps there is also a way to stop the other look ups as well.

Comment: @Parris sure, just store the deferreds somewhere and call `abort` on them in the `anyComplete` handler. I have edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a plugin which provides another version of `$.when()` with reversed semantics. It's modified from the actual jQuery implementation of `$.when()` so it's exactly the same as the original except that it waits for either the first `resolve`d promise, or all promised to be `reject`ed.

Just drop this code in right after you load jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $.reverseWhen = function( subordinate /* , ..., subordinateN */ ) {
    var i = 0,
      rejectValues = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ),
      length = rejectValues.length,

      // the count of uncompleted subordinates
      remaining = length !== 1 || ( subordinate && jQuery.isFunction( subordinate.promise ) ) ? length : 0,

      // the master Deferred. If rejectValues consist of only a single Deferred, just use that.
      deferred = remaining === 1 ? subordinate : jQuery.Deferred(),

      // Update function for both reject and progress values
      updateFunc = function( i, contexts, values ) {
        return function( value ) {
          contexts[ i ] = this;
          values[ i ] = arguments.length > 1 ? Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ) : value;
          if( values === progressValues ) {
            deferred.notifyWith( contexts, values );
          } else if ( !( --remaining ) ) {
            deferred.rejectWith( contexts, values );
          }
        };
      },

      progressValues, progressContexts, rejectContexts;

    // add listeners to Deferred subordinates; treat others as rejected
    if ( length > 1 ) {
      progressValues = new Array( length );
      progressContexts = new Array( length );
      rejectContexts = new Array( length );
      for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( rejectValues[ i ] && jQuery.isFunction( rejectValues[ i ].promise ) ) {
          rejectValues[ i ].promise()
            .done( deferred.resolve )
            .fail( updateFunc( i, rejectContexts, rejectValues ) )
            .progress( updateFunc( i, progressContexts, progressValues ) );
        } else {
          --remaining;
        }
      }
    }

    // if we're not waiting on anything, reject the master
    if ( !remaining ) {
      deferred.rejectWith( rejectContexts, rejectValues );
    }

    return deferred.promise();
  };
})(jQuery);
```