# Wait for the first of multiple jQuery Deferreds to be resolved?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

With jQuery I know that I can use `$.when()` to wait for *all of* multipe `Deferred`s to be resolved. (Or for the first one to be rejected.)

But is there a simple way to fire of multiple `Deferred`s and then just wait for *the first one* to be resolved?

For instance I want to try to use two similar AJAX web services either or which might be down or slow and then process whichever one replies first. And then I might use a third `Deferred` for a timeout.

Comment: See also [Find first available data source with jQuery Deferred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089335/find-first-available-data-source-with-jquery-deferred)

Comment: I filed another feature request against jQuery for this and related enhancements to `$.when()`: **[OPTIONS PARAMETER FOR $.WHEN() TO PROVIDE ALTERNATIVE SEMANTICS](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12325)**. It was also closed but [jaubourg](https://github.com/jaubourg) added good analysis and suggestions that will help anyone interested in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Kevin B's code, here's an approach that uses a master Deferred object:

```
var masterDeferred = new $.Deferred(),
    reqOne = $.post("foo.php"),
    reqTwo = $.post("bar.php");

masterDeferred.done(function() {
    // do stuff
});

reqOne.done(function() {
    masterDeferred.resolve();
});
reqTwo.done(function() {
    masterDeferred.resolve();
});
```

I think I'm right in saying that the simplest form of resolving the masterDeferred would be :

```
reqOne.done(masterDeferred.resolve);
reqTwo.done(masterDeferred.resolve);
```

But separate done functions will allow you to branch internally and call `.resolve()`, `.reject()`, `.resolveWith(...)` or `.rejectWith(...)` as appropriate, together with `masterDeferred` callbacks of the general form :

```
masterDeferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks );
```

Comment: Isn't there a risk that masterDeferred() will be called twice? Is there a defined behaviour for that?

Comment: No risk at all. A Deferred object (or its Promise) can only be resolved or rejected ONCE. Further attempts to resolve or reject will do precisely nothing, and will not generate an error providing the Deferred (or its Promise) has not been destroyed (and is within scope).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way would be to abort the other request when one of the two finishes, though you could also check the state of the deferred, the syntax of which will depend on your jQuery version which is why I go with abort for now.

```
function doStuff(data) {
    alert( "Hello World!" );
}
var reqOne = $.post("foo.php"),
reqTwo = $.post("bar.php");

reqOne.done(function(data){
    reqTwo.abort();
    finished = true;
    doStuff(data);
});
reqTwo.done(function(data){
    reqOne.abort();
    finished = true;
    doStuff(data);
});
```

Comment: Well it does seem totally simple (-: A more flexible `when()` could still be useful though ...

Comment: It would be nice if `$.when` would use `notify` as each deferred is resolved so that we could use the `progress` method.

Comment: Updated to get rid of finished variable