# jQuery $.wait() for *all* deferred's to be rejected?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

jQuery has a nice feature of its `Deferred` API, `$.wait()` for working with multiple `Deferred`s / `Promise`s. It returns when:

- **All** of the `Deferred`s have been `resolve()`d

*or*

- **One** of the `Deferred`s has been `reject()`ed

Most of the time this is what you want, but sometimes you want to know when **all** of them have been `reject()`ed.

**Is there a simple or elegant way to do something like `$.wait()` but only when all `Deferred`s have been rejected?**

(There may be other use cases but mine is to combine this with [waiting for the first of several Deferred's to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977192/wait-for-the-first-of-multiple-jquery-deferreds-to-be-resolved/11977529#comment15968825_11977529).)

Comment: Related but not the same: [jQuery.when - Callback for when ALL Deferreds are no long 'unresolved' (either resolved or rejected)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824615/jquery-when-callback-for-when-all-deferreds-are-no-long-unresolved-either-r)

Comment: I filed another feature request against jQuery for this and related enhancements to `$.when()`: **[OPTIONS PARAMETER FOR $.WHEN() TO PROVIDE ALTERNATIVE SEMANTICS](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12325)**. It was also closed but [jaubourg](https://github.com/jaubourg) added good analysis and suggestions that will help anyone interested in this question.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of how the Promise specification is likely going for the future with a `PromiseInspection` object, here's a jQuery add-on function that tells you when all promises are done, whether fulfilled or rejected:

```
// pass either multiple promises as separate arguments or an array of promises
$.settle = function(p1) {
    var args;
    if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
          args = p1;
    } else {
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    }

    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, value: function() {
                return fulfilled ? val: undefined;
            }, reason: function() {
                return !fulfilled ? val: undefined;
            }
        };
    }
    return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
        // if incoming value, not a promise, then wrap it in a promise
        if (!p || (!(typeof p === "object" || typeof p === "function")) || typeof p.then !== "function") {
            p = $.Deferred().resolve(p);
        }
        // Now we know for sure that p is a promise
        // Make sure that the returned promise here is always resolved with a PromiseInspection object, never rejected
        return p.then(function(val) {
            return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
        }, function(reason) {
            // convert rejected promise into resolved promise
            // this is required in jQuery 1.x and 2.x (works in jQuery 3.x, but the extra .resolve() is not required in 3.x)
            return $.Deferred().resolve(new PromiseInspection(false, reason));
        });
    })).then(function() {
          // return an array of results which is just more convenient to work with
          // than the separate arguments that $.when() would normally return
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    });
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
$.settle(promiseArray).then(function(inspectionArray) {
    inspectionArray.forEach(function(pi) {
        if (pi.isFulfilled()) {
            // pi.value() is the value of the fulfilled promise
        } else {
            // pi.reason() is the reason for the rejection
        }
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that `$.settle()` will always fulfill (never reject) and the fulfilled value is an array of `PromiseInspection` objects and you can interrogate each one to see if it was fulfilled or rejected and then fetch the corresponding value or reason.  See the demo below for example usage:

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y0gjs31r/

Comment: It seems this code can be improved/simplified by returning an `Error(reason)` if the promise rejects, and the value if it resolves, instead of dealing with `PromiseInspection`. Then, in the consumer, you can just test for `result instanceof Error` to find promises that originally rejected and get their rejection reason.

Comment: @cjbarth - Yes, that is another way to do it.  Some prefer this way, some that way.  Both work fine.  At one time, there was some standards discussion around using something like the `PromiseInspection` object for these types of uses, but I don't know whether that's still a likely direction or not - that's why it was done this way.  I agree, it might seem a bit simpler to do it the way you suggested.  That does require that all possible rejections of all promises you're using reject with an `instanceof Error` which is reasonable, but not always done.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem lately: I think that occurs because `$.when` is more of a `Promise.all` implementation.

I wasn't able to find a `Promise.allSettled` alternative in the jQuery documentation and across the web so here's my attempt to get it:

```js
const deferredsAllSettled = deferreds => {
    const settlements = [];

    deferreds.forEach(deferred => {
        const settlement = jQuery.Deferred();

        deferred.always(settlement.resolve);

        settlements.push(settlement);
    });

    const returnedDeferred = $.Deferred();

    jQuery.when
        .apply(jQuery, settlements)
        .then(() =>
            returnedDeferred.resolve(
                deferreds.map(deferred => deferred.promise())
            )
        );

    return returnedDeferred.promise();
};
```

NOTE: I've written that for a utils file so the `Promise.allSettled` one-only *iterable* parameter signature was ok for me, if you want to write it in the `$.when` spirit (passing and getting the `$.Deferred`s as separate arguments) you'll have to write a little more...

Comment: Please add the relevant code in your answer as well, since the link provided may not work in near future. thanks